# SOLR - How to get N most frequents terms and number of occurence in collection

Tags: solr

I would like to find the most frequents terms with their number of occurence in a field of my collection.

So far, I tried using :

- facet
- term vector component
- luke

The problem is, for each kind of those method, I'm unable to get the terms that are most frequent in the specific field of the collection. Instead, I get the number of document having at least on occurence.

Example with luke :

On a collection having 30 documents, for this query : admin/luke?fl=fr_body&numTerms=50

I get :

```
topTerms: [
30,
"extrait",
30,
"dire",
30,
"déjà",
30,
"enfin",
30,
"etc",
30,
"comédi",
30,
"deux",
30,
...
]
```

Is there any way to do this using solr ? If possible, I would love a way to do it when I can also use some filter query on other field of my index.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the "terms" component like you have stated and then use termfreq function. Take a look at this https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/function-queries.html#termfreq-function

May be someone else has a more elegant solution for you.

Comment: @WinnieDaPooh, thank you for your answer. But the termfreq function can only give me the count of occurence for a list of term that I would provide. What I want, is a request telling me wich terms are the most used in the index and how many occurences there is for each one of them.